# Which GMAIL notifier for Ubuntu 9.04 is the best?

Tags: linux, gmail, notifications

I would also want the "unread" count to appear next to the notification icon.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[gm-notify](https://launchpad.net/gm-notify) - A simple and lightweight highly Ubuntu 9.04 integrated GMail Notifier which takes advantages of the new and nice notify-osd and indicator-applet.

[Setup and configuration](http://maketecheasier.com/gmail-notifier-for-ubuntu-904/2009/05/11) gm-notify

Comment: It does not show the "unread" count as I have asked.

Answer (score 1):

I use [CheckGmail](http://checkgmail.sourceforge.net/), it:

- Notifies on New Mail
- Previews New Messages
- Open New Messages (without a browser)
- Can Blink LEDs (I think that's cool.)

While unread count isn't part of the icon, it shows when you hover.

Answer (score 0):

[Gmail Notifier](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/173?application=firefox&id=173&vid=504) Firefox extension shows the in box and unread mails information

or

Have look on this link http://ubuntu-tutorials.blogspot.com/2007/03/gmail-notifier-for-your-ubuntu-desktop.html

[image]

Comment: Still no "unread" count in the desktop notification icon...

Answer (score 0):

If you're only considering to check webmail like Gmail and you've got Firefox running anyway, then an alternative is to give the popular Firefox add-on [Webmail Notifier](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/4490) a try.
It features multiple account checking, and also settings for displaying unread mail counts. An icon will appear in the bottom right corner of Firefox's statusbar. Left/right clicking gives you options like unread count, and opening your Gmail inbox in a tab.

Comment: Thanks but I am running Chrome + the reason I am asking is that my browser window is on a different virtual desktop.